Derivate problem
Let $f$ be continuous on $[a, b]$ and differentiable on $(a, b)$ with $f(c) = 0$ for some $c \in [a, b]$. If there exists $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\vert f'(x) \vert \leq M \vert f(x) \vert$, $\forall x \in [a, b]$, then $f(x) = 0$, $\forall x \in [a, b]$.
The case $c = a$ is often studied in this context, For example
[1] [2] [3] [4]
I am wondering if the result remains true if $c \neq a$.

I will write the proof for the interval $[0,1]$ and let you modify it for a general interval.
Let $g(x)=f(tx+c)$. This is well defined for $x \in [0,1]$ as long as $0 \le t+c \le 1$ or $-c \le t \le -c+1$.
Now $g(0)=0$ and $|g'(x)|\le M|t||g(x)|$. By the case $c=a$ handled in your links we get $g(x)=0$ for all $x$. I will let you check that if $t=-c$ then $tx+c$ takes all values between $0$ and $c$ and when  $t=-c+1$, $tx+c$ takes all values between $c$ and $1$, This gives $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.
